# RetroPie issues

Tags: retropie, emulation, pi-b+

[image: Broken Emulator?]

I recently set up RetroPie on my B+.
What is wrong with N64 emulator?
I have graphic errors and no sound.

(Sorry for issues with thread. I am new to this.)

Comment: There's no way to answer this question without more detailed information from RetroPie's logs. There are a few swing-in-the-dark suggestions listed in [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RetroPie/comments/3fr9mm/a_few_issues_with_retropie_and_n64_emulation/?st=iy0f6eqf&sh=a3cc5a5e), and at [RetroPie's Github](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/sound-issues). You'll note the Reddit thread also suggests that N64 emulation is not wonderful in RetroPie - you may just be experiencing 'normal' conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [RetroPi N64 ROM compatibility list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wjzbu90l6eCEW1w6ar9NtfyDBQrSPILQL5MbRSpYSzw). Unfortunately, I don't recognize the game from your screenshot to point you to the relevant line, however, note that only about 10% of the listed games are marked as stable.